# i want connect mvc project with angular4

Tags: c#, angular, model-view-controller

My Mvc project structure like that 
[image: 1]

and i want to connect angular with Mvc how can i do please help me

[image: 2]

Comment: Never write `throw ex;`.

Comment: This is _far_ too broad of a question for Stack Overflow

Comment: but my angular4 can not sent to localhost mvc get request

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can add Angular solution folder to your MVC solution wherever you want. MVC won't compile it and treat it as simple asset folder. Just create a new folder for your Angular solution is fine.

If you want to use Angular in your MVC project. In my opinion, you need to build your Angular. Copy the `<app-root></app-root>` tag to your *.cshtml file then include the three generate JS files: main, inline, polyfill from the "dist" folder into your *.cshtml.

Comment: i know your solution but i want connect different folder level  two different project (mvc and angular4)

Comment: I don't think different folder level is an issue. Because they are different framework. MVC won't touch any Angular codes.